# QQuickImage convert to QImage

Tags: c++, qml, qtquick2, qt5.3

I've been using QZXing to decode QR code, my QML looks like this

```
Image{ 
    width:300
    height:300
    id:imageToDecode
    source:"qr.jpg"
    cache: true
}
```

and when i pass it into C++ file, it has to be converted into a QImage type,
in the code the original coder wrote like this

```
QGraphicsItem *item = qobject_cast<QGraphicsItem*>(imageObj);
```

and then use QGraphicsItem to construct a QImage,however this will always return 0 after conversion, since QGraphicsItem does not inherit QObject

straight conversion like

```
QImage*item = qobject_cast<QImage*>(imageToDecode);
```

will not work for same reason,ive been using

```
imageObj->inherits("objectName");
```

to test which one it can be converted to, but there is none i can find
my point is to convert QML Image into QImage.

Comment: You can't cast QGraphicsItem to QImage, because it is very different data types. I suspect that you have QGraphicsPixmapItem (inheritor of QGraphicsItem ), so you can use QGraphicsPixmapItem::pixmap() to get your image (and after it convert it to QImage).

Comment: Which version of Qt Quick, ie. what version you have in qml `import QtQuick x.x`? Which version of Qt? Just add relevant tags.

Comment: Also, your C++ snippets, are they real code? If yes, then show how these `imageObj` and `imageToDecode` are declared and initialized in C++, ie. what they are.

Comment: the way i wish to convert is like<code>

Comment: im using QtQuick 2.2, with Qt version 5.3, the imageObj is passsed from QML, which is a QML Image item, the way it is passed is exactly the way in the qzxing example, and i can actually get this item in C++, it looks fine, the only problem is after it is casted, its gone. (item=0)

Comment: the way i wish it to work is to convert it into a QGraphicsItem first, then make it a QImage by extracting the data from the QGraphcisItem

Comment: You are using Qt5 and Qt Quick 2, so `QGraphicsItem` no longer has anything to do with it (as far as I know). You want `QQuickItem` with Qt5.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Qt5 or greater and QtQuick 2.0 or greater you can't render the Image element to QGraphicsItem or anything related to QGraphics since from Qt5 the backend for QML is scenegraph and not QGraphics. 
So now going forward with Qt5.3 and you if access the Image element in C++, it will be casted to a QQuickImage internally, but still you can't extract image from Image element since QQuickImage has not been made public yet.
Ref. http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/32767

The solution they have proposed for now is to use QQuickImageProvider.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for answering. Yea ive seen that thread, and ive realize this object is a QQuickImage and i can not extract anything from it. Maybe i didnt understood the way to use, but i think the QQuickImageProvider can only give image from C++ to QML, not the way back. Anyway, is there any solution that i can convert the QQuickImage to a QImage?

Comment: `    QGraphicsItem *item = qobject_cast<QGraphicsItem*>(imageObj);       QImage img(item->boundingRect().size().toSize(), QImage::Format_RGB32);
    img.fill(QColor(255, 255, 255).rgb());
    QPainter painter(&img);
    QStyleOptionGraphicsItem styleOption;
    item->paint(&painter, &styleOption);` apparently this is the way how it used to construct the QImage, i think i need to rewrite this part now, just having no idea on how to do it

Comment: As i said earlier there's no way, since QQuickImage API's are not public. If you stick with Qt Quick 2.0 or greater and Qt5 you cannot cast Image element to QGraphics*.

Comment: Yes QQuickImageProvider gives image from C++ to QML, but anyhow you were going to comeback to C++ for processing ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found something that may (or may not) be a workaround to this issue.

Within the Image that is assigned the preview source, I call grabToImage() in order to create a QQuickItemGrabResult object and then in C++, I call the image() function on that object.  It seems to work.

## QML

```
Image {
  id:imageToDecode
  MouseArea {
    anchors.fill:parent
    onClicked: parent.grabToImage(function(result)
      decoder.decodeImageQML(result); })
    }
 }
```

## C++

```
QImage ImageHandler::extractQImage(QObject *imageObj,
                     const double offsetX, const double offsetY,
                     const double width, const double height)
{
    QQuickItemGrabResult *item = 0;
    item = qobject_cast<QQuickItemGrabResult*>(imageObj);
    QImage item_image(item->image());
    ....
}
```